# Laravel 5.2 - How to implement register with api token without session?

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm looking for a way to create a api token after registration without session

And I also have a question:

Regular site have session to identify the current user

But in api How can I identify the current user if we do not create for him a session?

I'm having trouble with these questions

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/support/remote-auth use this package its a very amazing and easy to intigrate anfdprovide lots of feature for manage user in api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept is that in login request you send e-mail and password and you get the token.

In all next request you send always this token (so you know which user makes the request) and for this you also send other data (if they are necessary).

Of course you need to make sure this token is somehow unique so you can now exactly which user is making the request.

You can implement it on your own or you can take advantage on some ready components.

In fact in Laravel 5.2 you have `TokenGuard` built in so you can create simple token authentication out of the box. You can watch [this movie on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/5) for further details.

You can also use some other packages for example [JWT Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

Comment: JWT Auth tokens have 1 hour lifetime so the user should login again to get fresh token. this is not so good for mobile apps to login again and again!

Comment: @AliSherafat It depends on implementation, you can make it much longer or auto refresh token without user attention

Comment: thanks for your reply, by default in JWT tokens refresh per hour and other developers say not to change that value to bigger time because it becomes more insecure. it's a little hard for me to decide what to do? can you give a hint? please see this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371493/token-based-authentication-for-api-in-laravel-5-2-31?rq=1)